# Reuse window / tab when file is already open

Tags: windows, vim

I want to set a global shortcut that will open a certain file. When there already is a gvim window that has that file open, I want it to focus on that window, and select the tab with that file. If there isn't, I want it to be opened in a new gvim window, regardless of whether there already are other gvim windows.

I can do part of this with `--remote` and `--servername`, but I can't find a way to detect whether there already is a remote server running with the name I use, so I can't quite get everything to work together to come to what I described above.

Comment: The only solution I'm aware of is mac specific: https://github.com/vitorgalvao/autoswap_mac.

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out most can be done using the default behavior of --remote-silent. The whole setup is a matter of making an AutoHotkey script like this:

```
#!^+1::
  Run "c:\Program Files (x86)\vim\vim74\gvim.exe" --servername org --remote-silent %DROPBOX%\org\TODO.org
  WinActivate, TODO.org
Return
```

AHK is needed for the global hotkey as well as activating the window; vim (using --servername and --remote-silent) will start a new session called 'org' if there isn't one yet, and start it otherwise. It even gets the tab activation right when there already is a server called 'org' but if that server has another tab active.